# c++ : string constructor with char* memory leak

Tags: c++, string, pointers, memory-leaks

As per my understanding when we call `string` ctor with `char*` **deep copying** happens so the passed `char*` can be easily **deleted** after constructor call of string (is it?) and the new string can be used safely afterward.

```
char* cptr = new char[20];
cptr = "dynamic_cstring"; // will it make difference if i will use memset

std::cout << cptr << std::endl;

std::string str(cptr);

std::cout << str.c_str() << std::endl;

cptr = "another string"; // seems that string internal buffer is not pointing to cptr

std::cout << str.c_str() << std::endl;

delete[] cptr; // crashed at this line. why ?
```

How can i prevent memory leak when i am using  char* to initialize string? Or is it automatically cleaned ? What if i use something like:

```
cptr[0] = 's';

std::string str(cptr);

// cptr = "another string"; 

delete[] cptr;
```

Is delete necessary in this case?

Comment: `cptr = "dynamic_cstring";` doesn't do what you think.

Comment: you don't need `str.c_str()` in your cout statements. Also, you can initialise your string directly, by using `std::strnig str = "My string";`. That being said, if possible it is best to avoid any char* whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cptr = "dynamic_string"
```

This change the `char*` value, which is an address, to point to a string literal. The string literal resides in data segment of the assembled file and is not dynamically allocated. So you can't `delete` it.

Assigning a pointer to another address never copies the data, you should use `strncpy` to effectively copy the content (or set the characters one by one).